# On Windows 10 how do I display proxy settings from CLI

Tags: command-line, proxy, cygwin, curl

I need the proxy settings for a command line tool. I know it's set to auto-detect but I still need to know what they are exactly.

Note that if I do this in Chrome:

```
chrome://net-internals/#proxy
```

...then I get this:

```
http://[redactedIP]/wpad.dat
```

What is a *.dat file? Can we use one of these in Cygwin curl? What I'm trying to do is get SDKMAN to work.

Comment: have you downloaded it with curl and looked inside ?

Comment: Of course, since they are using a proxy, those settings were necessary for other software. I located the correct settings in 2 places. Maven's settings.xml and my IDE's configuration.

Comment: Since you can name a file anything you like, you can not safely conclude from the filename, what "kind" of file it is. You can use the `file` command to get at least an educated guess, based on common heuristics, what the file content could mean.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, since they are using a proxy, those settings were necessary for other software. I located the correct settings in 2 places. Maven's settings.xml and my IDE's configuration. You can also look for the HTTP_PROXY, NO_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables.